# Activity/adjective for keep re-mentioning a favor

Tags: adjectives

Let's say a person helps you study for an exam (as a favor). What is the activity/verb that describes that person when he keeps re-mentioning it, as to make you feel that you owe him something.

Is there a one-word verb (or adjective) for it?

For example,

**person1**: Can you give me a ride to the airport?

**person2**: Sorry, I'm busy.

**person1**: But I helped you study for your exam last week.

**person2**: Ok, I'll give you a ride.

Next week.

**person1**: Hey, I need some cash. You don't mind giving me some, since I helped you pass that exam two weeks ago.

**person2**: Ok, stop being such a (the word I'm looking for).

I believe many words could be used in this scenario, such as abusive or manipulative. However, I am looking for a more exact work, which describes the action of constant referencing of a previous favor, to make the other feel obligated to help.

Comment: ... _such a pain_?

Comment: Many good suggestions here. I'd say "milking it" likely will work best. You could say, "Stop milking that favor" or "You've already milked that favor for all it's worth." (Though I also like the suggested use of beholden for its dramatic ring.) Now I'm interested to hear what you use and how it works.

Comment: I agree. I like **milking it** the most. Though I'll wait for more suggestions. I was hoping for a verb that describes the person, rather than the favor. For example, You are `something` (to) me. In my native language, Arabic, we have an informal word/phrase for it.

Comment: Roronoa: A similar sentiment might be _stop laying a guilt trip on me_, although that isn't the noun you're looking for, either. One noun you might consider is **cadger**, which means _one who gets his living by trickery or begging; someone who mooches or tries to get something free_. That word doesn't imply a previously-granted favor, though, so it falls a little short, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with is that your friend is

> Milking it for all it's worth

Answer (score 1):

That activity might be called nagging or pestering, and the actor could be called a nag or a pest.

But really it's someone who doesn't understand the definition of the word "favor". A favor is something you do for someone without expecting anything in return.

Comment: This is one form of _wheedling_, but I don't believe there's a special term for this particular variant.

Answer (score 1):

A common phrase in American English is *call in a favor*.  This is generally used to indicate someone seeking to be paid back for previous favors given.

Your question seems to suggest a repeated nagging for one or more favors. This is not conveyed by that phrase.

A related phrase, usually used by a person in a power position because of prior favors granted, is *I own you*, indicating that the person previously favored has an unending obligation to the speaker. Further, the speaker is usually demanding rather than asking for the return benefit.

Comment: In my social circles, one can only *call in a favor* (also *call in a chit*) after someone says *thanks, I owe you one* [favor]. I think the nagger in question is asserting a debt that may not have been freely given... and I agree that there should be a word for this kind of passive aggression.

Answer (score 0):

Person 2's response could be, "Enough! Exactly how long must I be ***beholden*** to you for that *favor* you did for me?!"

> be·hold·en
>
> Function: adjective
>
> Etymology: Middle English, from past participle of beholden
>
> Date: 14th century
>
> Definition: being under obligation for a favor or gift : indebted
>
> example: *"I'm beholden to you"*

From Merriam-Webster Online

[related article on the psychology of generosity and doing/receiving favors](http://www.uncommon-knowledge.co.uk/articles/generosity.html)